# How to config hibernate isolation level for postgres

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table `ErrorCase` in postgres database. This table has one field `case_id` with datatype text. Its value is generated by format: `yymmdd_xxxx`. yymmdd is the date when the record insert to DB, xxxx is the number of record in that date.

For example, 3th error case on 2019/08/01 will have the `case_id` = 190801_0003. On 08/04, if there is one more case, its `case_id` will be 190804_0001, and go on.

I already using trigger in database to generate value for this field:

```sql
DECLARE
    total integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) INTO total  FROM public.ErrorCase WHERE create_at = current_date;
    IF (NEW.case_id is null) THEN 
        NEW.case_id = to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYMMDD_') || trim(to_char(total, '0000'));
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
```

And in Spring Project, I config the application properties for jpa/hibernates:

```
datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/table_name
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        hikari:
            poolName: Hikari
            auto-commit: false
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
```

Currently, it generates the case_id correctly.

However, when insert many records in nearly same time, it generates the same `case_id` for two record. I guess the reason is because of the isolation level. When the first transaction not yet committed, the second transaction do the SELECT query to build case_id. So, the result of SELECT query does not include the record from first query (because it has not committed yet). Therefore, the second `case_id` has the same result as the first one.

Please suggest me any solution for this problems, which isolation level is good for this case???

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using such an outdated version of the Hibernate dialect? Does it really not support current Postgres versions? Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

"*yymmdd is the date when the record insert to DB, xxxx is the number of record in that date*" - no offense but that is a horrible design.

You should have two separate columns, one `date` column and one `integer` column. If you want to increment the counter during an insert, make that date column the primary key and use `insert on conflict`. You can get rid that horribly inefficient trigger and more importantly that will be safe for concurrent modifications even with read committed.

Something like:

```
create table error_case
(
  error_date date not null primary key, 
  counter integer not null default 1
);
```

Then use the following to insert rows:

```
insert into error_case (error_date)
values (date '2019-08-01')
on conflict (error_date) do update 
   set counter = counter + 1;
```

No trigger needed and safe for concurrent inserts.

If you really need a text column as a "case ID", create a view that returns that format:

```
create view v_error_case
as
select concat(to_char(error_date, 'yymmdd'), '_', to_char(counter, '0000')) as case_id,
       ... other columns
from error_case;
```

Comment: Let me try this way. Btw, the design is requested by our customer.